# Creating png thumbnail with ffmpeg gives error msg "error padding picture"

Tags: ffmpeg, png, thumbnails, padding, jpeg

I am trying to create a thumbnail image of a video with padding on the top and bottom. It works well if I want to create a jpeg image, but in case of png it dumps the error msg "`error padding picture`"

The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -vframes 1 -i video.avi -padleft 0 -padright 0 -padtop 22 \
-padbottom 22 -s 128x84 quik.png
```

If I just change the output file to "`quik.jpeg`" it works. Is there any way to create a padded png image through ffmpeg? Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Sounds like a bug.  Have you tried with a newer version of FFmpeg perhaps using the [video filter for padding](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) instead of the individual padding flags?

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- you're using the `-pad` options. They're no longer even available in newer versions of ffmpeg; you should use the `pad` filter instead:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -vframes 1 -i video.avi \
  -vf scale=128:-1,pad=128:128:0:oh/2-ih/2 \
  quik.png
```

To break down that `-vf`:

```
scale=128:-1
```

Scales the image to 128 wide, using whatever height is appropriate for the aspect ratio.

```
pad=128:84:0:oh/2-ih/2
```

Pads the image to 128x84, placing the input image at a Y coordinate of `oh/2-ih/2` (where `oh` is the output height of 84, and `ih` is the height of the input image) such that it's centered in the output.

Note that this filter string won't work if you have videos that are taller than they are wide (and hence need horizontal padding instead of vertical). The solution, I leave to the reader.

Comment: I am currently using 0.6.2 version. Not very sure if I can upgrade right away to a newer version because of other reasons. The video filters (-vf) is not supported in 0.6.2. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend upgrading. The entire 0.6 branch is several years old; even the most recent version on that branch (0.6.6) has become unmaintained. A newer version of ffmpeg will give you faster, better encoding and decoding of a wider variety of formats, as well as filters (which are all kinds of useful).